# Loop queue algorithm issue

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I'm trying to do the following, and can't figure out how exactly do It without crashing or infinite looping:

I have to create a queue in which I have to distribute different tasks a different number of times each, alternatively with this kind of info:

- **Task X: [NextOne,LastOne]**

  - Task 1: [30,32]
  - Task 2: [76,81]
  - Task 3: [2,2]
  - Task 4: [5,8]

Meaning that "Task X" will be made "LastOne - NextOne" times, and if both are equal, it won't be enqueued, and they enter the queue in X order.
With this example, the queue should look like:

```
FIRST
Task1[30]
Task2[76]
Task4[5]
Task1[31]
Task2[77]
Task4[6]
Task1[32]
Task2[78]
Task4[7]
Task2[79]
Task4[8]
Task2[80]
Task2[81]
LAST
```

It's not a language issue, it's more of an algorithm issue I have here. Using PHP I've made the following:

```
$tasks = array(
'Task1' => array(30,32),
'Task2' => array(76,81),
'Task3' => array(2,2),
'Task4' => array(5,8)
);


$aux = array();
$i=0;
foreach($tasks as $s=>$n) {
    $aux[$i]['task'] = $s;
    $aux[$i]['times'] = $n[1]-$n[0];
    $aux[$i]['first'] = $n[0];
    $i++;
}
```

But as you imagine this actually does nothing, just change the shape of the information. I'm really stuck here I don't know why, this actually shouldn't be hard to figure out. I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python (I may be misinterpreting your "it's not a language issue" comment - forgive me):

```
tasks = [
    ("Task1", 30, 32),
    ("Task2", 76, 81),
    ("Task3", 2, 2),
    ("Task4", 5, 8) ]

while not tasks == []:
    # Pop first task off the current list
    (n, s, e) = tasks[0]
    tasks = tasks[1:]

    print n, s
    if s != e:
        tasks.append( (n, s+1, e) )
```

Sorry it's not in php - it's not my forte, but perhaps this'll help? Output:

```
Task1 30
Task2 76
Task3 2
Task4 5
Task1 31
Task2 77
Task4 6
Task1 32
Task2 78
Task4 7
Task2 79
Task4 8
Task2 80
Task2 81
```

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpful.It's OK in Python, that's not a problem, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can use `$s` as a key for the hash(or array equivalent) and just **increase the value by 1 whenever it encounters the element with the same key**. The default value would be 0 in this case.

For example,

Task1 => array(30,32)

will be come in order like

```
Task1[30] (default value to 0)
...
...
Task1[31] (add 1 which becomes 1)
...
Task1[32] (add 1 which becomes 2)
```

This means that Task1 has appeared 3 times overall, and the final `times` value should be 2.

I think you can use `array_key_exists` helper function to check if certain task had appeared previously.

Answer (score 1):

**In C#**

The result is as you wish.

I added a number as a flag: 1 = Not to be enqueued, 2 = Last record of the task.

Not efficient but works!

```
private static void Main()
{
    var tasks = new Dictionary<string, int[]>
                    {
                        {"Task1", new[] {30, 32, 0}},
                        {"Task2", new[] {76, 81, 0}},
                        {"Task3", new[] {2, 2, 0}},
                        {"Task4", new[] {5, 8, 0}}
                    };
    int loopCounter = 0;
    Console.WriteLine("FIRST");
    while (loopCounter < tasks.Count)
    {
        foreach (var task in tasks)
        {
            if (task.Value[0] == task.Value[1])
            {
                if (task.Value[2] == 2)
                {
                    loopCounter++;
                    Console.WriteLine(task.Key + "[" + task.Value[0] + "]");
                    task.Value[2] = 1;
                }
                else if (task.Value[2] == 0)
                {
                    loopCounter++;
                    task.Value[2] = 1;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(task.Key + "[" + task.Value[0] + "]");
                task.Value[0]++;
                if (task.Value[0] == task.Value[1])
                    task.Value[2] = 2;
            }
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("LAST");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Output:

```
FIRST
Task1[30]
Task2[76]
Task4[5]
Task1[31]
Task2[77]
Task4[6]
Task1[32]
Task2[78]
Task4[7]
Task2[79]
Task4[8]
Task2[80]
Task2[81]
LAST
```

Hope this helps.